# Will a metal dough scraper damage a granite countertop?

Tags: baking, equipment

I have a brand new granite countertop, and a lovely metal dough scraper that a friend gave me. Am I likely to damage the counter if I use the scraper regularly directly on the granite surface?

I have kneaded dough twice on it, and very tentatively used the metal scraper with no ill-effect. I don't want to try again and scrape more strongly only to find out that actually the two are not a good combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Granite is extremely tough, using a scraper on it won't damage it provided you use it properly. If you repeatedly brought the corner of the blade of the scraper down on it then it might conceivably chip but that would take a great deal of energy. I've had granite for years and use scrapers often with no issues.

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry, it won't scratch. You can look at where both objects are on [Mohs scale of mineral hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness).

From [the Strength and Hardness Ratings of Granite and Marble](https://www.granitemarblewa.com/a-peek-at-the-strength-and-hardness-ratings-of-granite-and-marble/):

> Granite has a Mohs hardness rating of seven.

From [Mohs Hardness Test](http://www.rocksandminerals.com/hardness/mohs.htm):

> The steel blade of the average knife usually has a hardness of about 5.5.

(I assume the scraper and a knife have equal hardness).

Comment: Also, a dough scraper is unlikely made from hardened and tempered steel that comes close to 5.5 (which seems to be considered roughly equivalent to 59HRC. Yes, that is a medium-hard knife.).